# How to add line number into each line?

Tags: scala, text, apache-spark

suppose these are my data:

```
‘Maps‘ and ‘Reduces‘ are two phases of solving a query in HDFS.
‘Map’ is responsible to read data from input location.
it will generate a key value pair.
that is, an intermediate output in local machine.
’Reducer’ is responsible to process the intermediate.
output received from the mapper and generate the final output.
```

and i want to add a number to every line like below output:

```
1,‘Maps‘ and ‘Reduces‘ are two phases of solving a query in HDFS.
2,‘Map’ is responsible to read data from input location.
3,it will generate a key value pair.
4,that is, an intermediate output in local machine.
5,’Reducer’ is responsible to process the intermediate.
6,output received from the mapper and generate the final output.
```

save them to file.

i've tried:

```
object DS_E5 {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    var i=0
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("prep").setMaster("local")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val sample1 = sc.textFile("data.txt")
    for(sample<-sample1){
      i=i+1
      val ss=sample.map(l=>(i,sample))
      println(ss)
    }
 }
}
```

but its output is like blew :

```
Vector((1,‘Maps‘ and ‘Reduces‘ are two phases of solving a query in HDFS.))
...
```

How can i edit my code to generate an output like my favorite output?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`zipWithIndex` is what you need here. It maps from `RDD[T]` to  `RDD[(T, Long)]` by adding an index on the second position of the pair.

```
sample1
   .zipWithIndex()
   .map { case (line, i) => i.toString + ", " + line }
```

or using string interpolation (see a comment by @DanielC.Sobral)

```
sample1
    .zipWithIndex()
    .map { case (line, i) => s"$i, $line" }
```

Comment: Might need `i+1` to if counting starts at 1.

Comment: thank you @zero323, it is ok , but there are parentheses yet (1,line), i want to remove these parentheses.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand. Do you an output to be `RDD[String]`?

Comment: this is your code output : (0,‘Maps‘ and ‘Reduces‘ are two phases of solving a query in HDFS.) but i want this output: 0,‘Maps‘ and ‘Reduces‘ are two phases of solving a query in HDFS.

Comment: Personally, I prefer string interpolation and wish `+` on strings would disappear. :)

Comment: +1 although wouldn't .read() be read by multiple executors so the order of the index set by zipWithIndex() is not guranteed? In other words, yes you get all lines numbered but those indicies aren't necessary stable and depend on how many executors you had, how HDFS file is distributed among them etc?

Comment: @Tagar For `textFile` order of partitions and values in partition comes from the input format logic. It is stable and consecutive splits are assigned to consecutive partitions.

Answer (score 2):

By calling `val sample1 = sc.textFile("data.txt")` you are creating a new [RDD](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD).

If you need *just an output*, you can try to use next code:

> `sample1.zipWithIndex().foreach(f => println(f._2 + ", " + f._1))`

Basically, by using this code, you will do this:

1. Using `.zipWithIndex()` will return new `RDD[(T, Long)]`, where `(T, Long)` is a [Tuple](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Tuple2), `T` is a previous RDD elements datatype (`java.lang.String`, I believe) and `Long` is an index of element in RDD.
2. You performed **transformation**, now you need to make an **action**. `foreach`, *in this case*, suits very well. What is basically does: it applies your statement to every element in current RDD, so we just call quickly formatted `println`.