# Remove first and last row from the text file in pyspark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I have file like below

```
H201908127477474
123|sample|customer|3433
786|ex|data|7474737
987|solve|data|6364
T3 637373
```

I want to remove the first row and last row from the file. Please give me some solution in pyspark

I am using this to load the file

```
df=spark.read.format('csv').load('sample.txt')
```

Comment: Need to remove H201908127477474 and T3 637373 row from the file

Comment: it won't specifically remove the first and last rows, but `df = spark.read.csv('sample.txt', sep="|", mode="DROPMALFORMED")` might work for you in this case.

Comment: After using this it returned only
```+--------------------+
|                 _c0|
+--------------------+
|H201908127477474NO...|
|T3 637373...|
+--------------------+```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no easy way to drop rows by line number because Spark DataFrames do not by default have a concept of order<sup>1</sup>. There is no "first" or "last" row - each row is treated as an independent block of structured data. This is fundamental to spark and is what what allows it to distribute/parallelize computing - each executor can pick up an arbitrary chunk of the data and process is.

Although your question asks how to drop the first and last rows, I assume what you actually want is to keep the data which follow the correct schema.

If you know the correct schema ahead of time, you can pass it into `spark.read.csv` and use `mode="DROPMALFORMED"`:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType, StringType, StructField, StructType

schema = StructType(
    [
        StructField('a', IntegerType()),
        StructField('b', StringType()),
        StructField('c', StringType()),
        StructField('d', IntegerType())
    ]
)
df = spark.read.csv('sample.txt', sep="|", mode="DROPMALFORMED", schema=schema)
#+---+------+--------+-------+
#|  a|     b|       c|      d|
#+---+------+--------+-------+
#|123|sample|customer|   3433|
#|786|    ex|    data|7474737|
#|987| solve|    data|   6364|
#+---+------+--------+-------+
```

Notes:

1. You can introduce order via a `sort` or with a `Window` function. See: [Pyspark add sequential and deterministic index to dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52318016/pyspark-add-sequential-and-deterministic-index-to-dataframe) (and check out the posts linked in the question).
2. If you truly wanted to drop the first and last rows, you can [add line numbers to rdd with `zipWithIndex()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31212962/how-to-add-line-number-into-each-line), and use this to filter out the smallest and largest line numbers.